# Why is server callback triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have the following simple setup:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('incoming');
}).listen(8127);
```

When I make a request from a browser, it ouputs `incoming` continuously within some pretty long interval. Why does that happen?

I suspect that a browser connects to a server, sends some data, but since I don't call `res.end()` anywhere in my code, it gets no response. So it waits for some time, and sends requests again. Is it correct? If so, how can I see it happening on a lower level?

Comment: You can try dumping `res`. Typically a single page load will trigger 3 or more HTTP requests (typically at least 2). One request would be the main request. Another for the tab icon. Another for an attempt to see if you support HTTPS (this is part of the HTTPS everywhere effort in order to secure the internet). This is assuming your page is a plain text page with no media content (images, videos, sound etc.) and no external css or js.

Comment: @slebetman, thanks, but those requests are happening within the interval of about 5 minutes and there are about 10 of them before a browser shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. According to [HTTP/1.1 memo](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4):

> If an HTTP/1.1 client sends a request which includes a request body,
>       but which does not include an Expect request-header field with the
>       “100-continue” expectation, and if the client is not directly 
>       connected to an HTTP/1.1 origin server, and if the client sees the
>       connection close before receiving any status from the server, the 
>       client SHOULD retry the request.

browser make request retries after some period of time.

From node.js side: `http.createServer` callback is working by EventEmitter model and called every time server takes request. If you want to explore what happens with response object - you can try to start server with `--inspect` flag and debug.